# Different data with same series name

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to display my data on a bar chart using highcharts. It works fine with unique names but when I tried to show different data with same names then it was displaying data on one bar but I want to display it on separate bars. So how can I display data with same names on different bars.
Here is link of my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0jfe3nt/3/)

```
{
                name: '10100',
                y: 8451720
            },                              {
                name: '10100',
                y: 1456480
            },                              {
                name: '13050',
                y: 187940
            },                              {
                name: '13050',
                y: 6991100
            },                              {
                name: '13050',
                y: 7167320              }]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> uniqueNames: Boolean
>
> When uniqueNames is true, points are placed on the X axis according to their names. If the same point name is repeated in the same or another series, the point is placed on the same X position as other points of the same name. When uniqueNames is false, the points are laid out in increasing X positions regardless of their names, and the X axis category will take the name of the last point in each position.

So you need to add attribute uniqueNames: false to xAxis